# Why trend between smooth plots (of GAM) and scatter plot is the opposite?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

Below is an example using `mtcars`.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mtcars$disp,mtcars$mpg)
plot(mtcars$hp,mtcars$mpg)

library(mgcv)
gam1 <- gam(mtcars$mpg ~ s(mtcars$disp) + s(mtcars$hp), family = Gamma)
plot(gam1, page = 1)
```

The strange thing is that if I draw the relationship between disp & mpg, or hp & mpg, they are negatively related (Fig1). But after using GAM, their relation became positive (Fig2). How can they contradict?[image: Fig1] [image: Fig2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?gam.plot`:

> gam.plot() takes a fitted gam object produced by gam() and plots the component
>   smooth functions that make it up, on the scale of the linear
>   predictor.

Since, canonical link for `Gamma` distribution is `inverse` (and you didn't provide your own link), linear predictor is on a scale of $1/\text{mpg}$, and so it was plotted.